# NavigationDrawer com ExpandableListView

Tags: android

Estou precisando fazer um *drawer* como o da imagem abaixo, exceto pelo *header* dos itens. Preciso que a lista tenha os itens e os subitens. E que somente se o item tiver subitem mostrar a seta para expandir. Já procurei alguns tutorias na net mas não encontrei algo como preciso. Alguém pode me dar alguma ajuda, algum exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode fazê-lo baseado-se nesse projeto https://github.com/rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ActionBarCompat.

Comment: Eu testei esse mais ainda não é o que eu preciso. O que eu preciso é que se um item da listview tiver filhos (subitens), que esse item fique expansível.